# how to change imported csv variables in sas

Tags: csv, sas

I imported a csv in SAS however the format was incorrect in the original file. I am working with addresses, so for example, the city will be incorrectly concatenated to the street variable or the zip code will be in the city variable. How to set parameters after importing. when I tried to use set length, it gave me a message saying that the length was already set before and that I should work with the DATA step. I do not know where exactly to do this.

Comment: Show some sample csv data, describe how it is imported, and examples of SAS code you tried.

Comment: Show your code.  Sounds like you added a LENGTH statement after a SET statement so the variables LENGTH had already been defined when SAS looked at what variables were in the incoming dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can manually define what and how lines are read into SAS. Here is an example from **Proc import**.

Just change the delimiter **;** in this case. Also, depending if your data has header row set the firstObs properly. Other than those, just list the variables and their attributes.

```
data WORK.Imported;
%let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
infile 'c:\input\datafile.csv' delimiter =';' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=13106 firstobs=2 ;
    informat first_var $15. ;
    informat second_var $24. ;
    informat third_var best32. ;
    /*... add as many as your data has */
    format first_var $15. ;
    format second_var $24. ;
    format third_var best12. ;
    /*... add as many as your data has */
    input
    First_var $
    Second_var $
    CCM
    /*... add as many as your data has */
    ;
    if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */
run;
```

Lazy approach is just using proc import with guessingrows=max option:

```
proc import datafile="c:\imput\input.csv" out=imprted replace;
        DELIMITER=";" ;
        getnames=yes;
        guessingrows=MAX; 
run;
```

Be aware that in very large files this is going to ta long time. Usually better to set the rows 'sufficiently large' like 32k.

For more on importing see [proc import](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n18jyszn33umngn14czw2qfw7thc.htm). Or more generally on [importing/exporting](http://www.iuj.ac.jp/faculty/kucc625/sas/import.html)

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me as well, problem is there are some 'line breaks' used in the input csv file. If you replace all the line breaks with space, save the file, and then import in SAS - it will import the data correctly.
Easy way to do this is:

1. Press Ctrl+H to open the Find & Replace dialog box.
2. In the Find What field enter Ctrl+J. It will look empty, but you will see a tiny dot.
3. In the Replace With field, enter any value to replace line breaks. Usually, it is space to avoid 2 words join accidentally. If all you need is deleting the line breaks, leave the "Replace With" field empty.

[See this page for other ways:](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/)